# Best way to switch between two model class versions were generated from an .xsd file

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

Currently we have a project contains an .xsd file and the generated classes out of it. And it's used in multiple projects inside the solution.
Now we got a new version of the .xsd where there are many changes in the classes names, properties, etc..(some classes are still exactly the same)
But the issue is that we want to keep the old version so need to have the flexibility to switch on demand,I think maybe I can add a version value in the configuration to know what version it should use at the runtime.
my question is what is the best way to do so?
examples of the generated code, Old version:

```
    /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "1.1.1234.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class EventMessage
{
    private MessageHeader messageHeaderField;

    private StatusReport statusReportField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public MessageHeader MessageHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return this.messageHeaderField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.messageHeaderField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public StatusReport StatusReport
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusReportField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.statusReportField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "1.1.1234.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class MessageHeader
{

    private Identification identificationField;

    private string version_majorField;

    private string version_minorField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public Identification Identification
    {
        get
        {
            return this.identificationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.identificationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string version_major
    {
        get
        {
            return this.version_majorField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.version_majorField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string version_minor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.version_minorField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.version_minorField = value;
        }
    }

}
```

New Version example:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "1.1.1234.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class EventMessage
{

    private MessageHeader messageHeaderField;

    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public MessageHeader MessageHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return this.messageHeaderField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.messageHeaderField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("StatusReport", typeof(StatusReport))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SessionTermination", typeof(SessionTermination))]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "1.1.1234.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class MessageHeader
{

    private Identification_ComplexType identificationField;

    private MessageReference messageReferenceField;

    private Sender senderField;

    private Recipient recipientField;

    private string versionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public Identification_ComplexType Identification
    {
        get
        {
            return this.identificationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.identificationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public MessageReference MessageReference
    {
        get
        {
            return this.messageReferenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.messageReferenceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Sender Sender
    {
        get
        {
            return this.senderField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.senderField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Recipient Recipient
    {
        get
        {
            return this.recipientField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.recipientField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have complex classes and want to keep the new version and old version separated.  So I would create a main class for old version and second main class for new version and put the serialize classes in side the two main classes.